# vim using iterm2 cannot use colorscheme

Tags: macos, vim, iterm2

So I am trying to get colorscheme support in iterm2 on my mac. When I :colorscheme solarized this is what my screen looks like

[image]

Here is my main .vimrc

```
set nocompatible

let mapleader = ","

set backspace=2
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set noswapfile
set history=50
set ruler
set showcmd
set incsearch
set laststatus=2
set autoread

set ignorecase
set smartcase

set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set shiftround

set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·,nbsp:·

set textwidth=80
set colorcolumn=+1

"set number

set splitbelow
set splitright

set winwidth=84
set winheight=5
set winminheight=5
set winheight=999

set matchpairs+=<:>

" Treat <li> and <p> tags like the block tags they are
let g:html_indent_tags = 'li\|p'

set scrolloff=8
set sidescrolloff=15
set sidescroll=1

"if (&t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")) && !exists("syntax_on")
"  syntax on
"   set t_Co=256
"   set background=dark
"endif

" Load up all of our plugins
if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.bundles"))
  source ~/.vimrc.bundles
endif

filetype plugin indent on
```

And here is my plugin file

```
if &compatible
      set nocompatible
    end

    filetype off
    set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
    call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-runner.git'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-run-interactive'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/ctags.vim'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic' "Syntax Highlighting
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/tComment'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/HTML-AutoCloseTag'
Plugin 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive' "Make git awesome
Plugin 'tpope/vim-repeat'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'

Plugin 'Slava/vim-spacebars'
Plugin 'groenewege/vim-less'

Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline' "Awesome looking meta at bottom
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'

Plugin 'vim-scripts/matchit.zip'
Plugin 'vimwiki/vimwiki'
Plugin 'mattn/calendar-vim'

    call vundle#end()
    filetype on

    set t_Co=256
    set background=dark
    syntax enable
```

I have gone into the setting of iterm and set the reporting of the terminal to xterm-256color. I also added to my .zshrc the following lines

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the solarized colorscheme to your terminal too.

From the solarized-vim readme:

> IMPORTANT NOTE FOR TERMINAL USERS:
>
> If you are going to use Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI version like gvim or macvim), please please please consider setting your terminal emulator's colorscheme to used the Solarized palette.

You should download the solarized bundle from [here](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/files/solarized.zip) and unzip it.

Then open iTerm 2, go to `iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Colors`. At the bottom it should say `Load Presets`. Click that and choose `import` near the bottom. Go to where the downloaded solarized folder is and choose `solarized/iterm2-colors-solarized/Solarized Dark` (or Solarized Light). Then Solarized Dark (or Light) should be in the drop down menu.

Then everything should work fine.

Comment: So do I have to do that for every colorscheme I would want to use?

Comment: No, in my experience, solarized is the only one that causes troubles.